# Debug .net core Application System.StackOverflowException c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, stack-overflow

I have created a new .NET Core Console Application, that very simply outputs "Hello World!":
[Code of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3qA8.png)
It builds with no errors but when I do Start Debug (Green arrow), the application will start and have a System.StackOverflowException before running:
[Exception Thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pErcx.png)

I am unsure what is causing this issue, but whenever I use .NET Framework over .NET Core it will work.

Comment: Just a simple question: are you sure you have enough memory? C# Debugger + Visual Studio + Whatever you have also open?

Comment: Yes I have enough memory, I can run a .Net Framework version of the same code with all the same applications open and it runs fine @Martin

Comment: Don't post code, or error details as images. You have a text box there, put text in it.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it's a Console app, and there are no files at all in the project apart from Program.cs? I can't see anything wrong with your code at all, and the exception seems to be thrown before it even starts the Main method.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: `Debug/Windows/Exception Settings` and make sure `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` is turned on. This should point you to the place where the exception is risen, assuming it's in your code.

[image]

Comment: I have turned that on, I can see the following information in the Debug window:
'JsonApiGenerator.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.16\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Comment: Try and set a breakpoint in you Console.WriteLine line, and see if it stops there. And make sure your running in debug mode and not release mode. Try to create a new application without any changes and see if that works

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to the JustMock profiler.

Once I disabled this, I could successfully start the application in debug.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Hi Bradley,
I am part of the JustMock team. Could you please provide more information on the issue? I am particularly interested in what version of .NET Core you have installed on your machine. You can find the required information with the command: dotnet --info

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: this issue is still happening. i reviewed another persons machine with this issue and they had .net core < 3 installed which i think is the issue here as it doesnt fail on mine with many v3's installed still alongside .net5.
2.1.202,
2.1.526,
3.1.414,
3.1.20,
+ more .net5